# C# ComboBox using a Property in a Dictionary value as DisplayMember, and the Dictionary value itself as ValueMember

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Dictionary, and I'm trying to populate a ComboBox with it.  My Settings class has a string property called Symbol, which is what I want to display in the drop-down list, and I want comboBox.SelectedItem to be a Settings object. So far I've tried:

```
comboBox.DataSource = dictionary.Values.ToList();
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Symbol";
comboBox.ValueMember = null;
```

and

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dictionary.Values.ToList();
comboBox.DataSource = bindingSource;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Symbol";
comboBox.ValueMember = null;
```

I don't necessary need to bind the data for what I'm doing, I would be happy with adding everything one time in the constructor, but it seemed cleaner to use DataSource rather than looping through the dictionary.Values.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you confirm that `Symbol` is a property with a getter and not just a field? Also is your ComboBox displaying anything or does it remain empty?

Comment: Yes, it's a public property in it's base class

Comment: For now I've resolved this by iterating through the Dictionary and adding the values to comboBox.Items.  However I'm still curious why I can't get it to work with data binding.